# Sharing Variables Between Popup and Content Script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm new to JavaScript and trying to complete my first web-related JS project, but I'm running into a problem.

A Chrome extension I’m building presents users with a popup page which consists of four drop down fields. When the user submits the form, a JSON object is created in an empty div on the popup page itself with the user's four selections as its values. I didn't create this function.

A separate function that I did create parses the JSON on the pop-up page, converts it into an array and gets the array's values.

The last part is where I'm having trouble. The content script needds to take each value from the array, scan a webpage for divs with matching values, inject HTML into that div. The problem is that I can't share the array variable with the browserAction function in the content script, preventing me from running the array values against another page.

Nesting the functions doesn’t seem to work. I've tried making the variables in my script global, but since the innerHTML of the element where the object is stored is empty until the function runs it returns null when moved outside the function. I have a feeling there is an advanced technique to get around this but I have been unsuccessful finding a solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Pop up submit button**

```
<button onclick="setTimeout(loopTheArray, 1)" type="submit">Send</button>
```

**Variables That Need to be Global (I think)**

```
function loopTheArray(){
    var responseObject = document.getElementById('code').innerHTML;
    var responseParsed = JSON.parse(responseObject);
    var responseValues = Object.values(responseParsed); //variable that needs to be shared to content script
```

**Example of Object Created on the Pop Up Page**

```
{
  "country": "Value 1",
  "language": "Lang 1",
  "region": "Region 1",
  "sector": "Value 1"
}
```

Comment: 1. [onClick within Chrome Extension not working](//stackoverflow.com/q/13591983) 2. don't use `submit`, use a simple click listener as shown in #1 and 3. the popup page is different from the web page so you need messaging to communicate with the content script, there are many examples

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you.